# "To" vs. "for" in "gold for your business"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, sentence

As a marketing slogan could the following sentence be considered grammatical?

> Because happy customers are gold for your business.

Would it be better to say *to* instead of *for*? Or a rephrasing like:

> Because happy customers are their weight worth in gold to your business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It’s *customers*, not *costumers*.
2. The first is grammatical, but it’s not a very original or persuasive slogan.
3. The expression in the second is *worth their weight in gold* and not *their weight worth in gold*.
4. I’d try to come up with something different altogether, if I were you.

Comment: Thanks. You are probably right that I should try to come up with something more original...

Comment: Better still, pay money and hire a professional. If a job is worth doing, it's worth doing well; and if it's worth doing well, it's worth paying someone who knows how to do it.